# jQuery Get parameter value from URL and check radiobutton PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, checkbox, radio-button

Hi i have a from with few radio buttons to filter my data...I want to check url to make a radio button checked...How i can achieve that ??

Form:

```
<form method="post">
<div>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="scat" value="ABC" data-href="example.com?link=[value]">

    <label for="radio2">ABC</label>
</div>

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function()
  {
     window.location=$(this).attr('data-href')
  });
```

Its working fine for me all i want is to check parameters values in url and check that radio button...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

So, are you asking to check the appropriate radio button on page load, when there is a link value in the query string of the URL?

If so, you can do that in two steps: 1. parse the URL. 2. update the correct radio button.

I'm assuming in your example, that you meant to replace `[value]` with an example like `ABC` to match the rest of your example. In other words `<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="scat" value="ABC" data-href="example.com?link=ABC">`.

If so, then your javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        window.location=$(this).attr('data-href');
    });
    // parse the url:
    var link = window.location.search.match(/link=(\w+)/)[1];
    if (typeof link !== 'undefined') {
        // update the correct radio button:
        $('input[value="' + link + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for your time....but sorry the above code didn't work for me...

Comment: You need to give more info. I made 2 assumptions in my answer. One about clarifying what you are really asking, and one about the `[value]` placeholder that I assumed you left in accidentally. If my code doesn't work, then one or both of my assumptions is wrong. At least say which one.

Comment: I found my error sir...values stored in db has spaces between them like "abc de","stall mor" etc...Now i replace space with "-" in my URL...now how i can replace "-" with space in jquery...Thanks....